# Displaying pedigree of both husband and wife on same chart?

Tags: chart-type, pedigree

Is there a pedigree chart available with which I can make both my family tree and my wife's family tree on the same chart?

Both the trees have a common ancestor which is what I'm trying to figure out.

I don't use any genealogy software. Some elders in my family don't have access to the software, so have to do on paper first.

Comment: How many generations back are you expecting the common ancestor to appear, and thus how many generations are you trying to display?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A combined pedigree is easy if you put one of your children in the first generation (proband) position of any pre-printed pedigree chart (since you aren't using software). Or you could leave that box blank, even as you fill out the rest with you in the father box and your wife as mother. Most pre-printed charts have a limited number of generations, but can be linked to another sheet which extends the tree. (Each name in the rightmost column can become the first name on the next sheet).

[image: Combination pedigree]

Most lineage-linked genealogy software can generate this kind of chart very easily. Even if one maintains separate databases for different branches, a (temporary) combined tree can be created by importing the relevant names together. However a particular person would have to be in the tree to put in the 1st position on the chart.

Comment: Could you please also explain what do you mean by lineage-linked?

Comment: Lineage-based software lets you input people's names and link them as spouses or parents and children. You can add events, pictures or information sources, but these are optional (although very desirable). Some genealogy software is designed primarily to track research tasks rather than actually building a family tree. There is a trend that is driving development of event-based software that builds a tree through linked sources, and is striving to be more flexible in the kinds of inter-personal connections that can be made (godparents, adoptions, witnesses, etc).